# fit_xy() usage for cross_validation in Tidy Models

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am new to Tidy Models and liking it so far but have a question with using a non-formula interface for resampling/cross-validation. The way I understand it so far, in order for me to apply resampling()/cross validation, I should write a

- recipe with a formula: outcome ~ predictors

```
    rf_rec <- 
        recipe(y_graduated ~ ., 
               data = trainDat_predSet)
```

- specify a model

```
    # Setting Random Forest Model Specifications
        rf_model <-
          rand_forest() %>%
          set_engine("ranger") %>%
          set_mode("classification") %>%
          set_args(mtry = 3, 
                   trees = 50,
                   min_n = 5)
```

- create folds

```
    set.seed(1234)
    trainDatFolds <- 
      rsample::vfold_cv(data = trainDat, v = 5)
```

- put recipe and model specification in a workflow

```
    rf_workflow <- 
      workflow() %>%
      add_recipe(rf_rec) %>%
      add_model(rf_model)
```

- Then fit the resampling.

```
    rf_workflow %>% 
      fit_resamples(resamples = trainDatFolds,
                    metrics = metric_set(roc_auc, pr_auc, accuracy),
                    control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)
      )
```

For my purposes, it is far more convenient to be able to use a non-formula interface of outcome ~ predictors.

Without the recipe step and if I was doing resampling fit, I could easily use the function -
fit_xy() to specify the y - outcome and x - predictor set.

Is that an option for fitting in resampling?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not an x/y interface but an easy way to get there without a formula:

```r
library(recipes)

rec <- recipe(mtcars)
summary(rec)
#> # A tibble: 11 x 4
#>    variable type    role  source  
#>    <chr>    <chr>   <lgl> <chr>   
#>  1 mpg      numeric NA    original
#>  2 cyl      numeric NA    original
#>  3 disp     numeric NA    original
#>  4 hp       numeric NA    original
#>  5 drat     numeric NA    original
#>  6 wt       numeric NA    original
#>  7 qsec     numeric NA    original
#>  8 vs       numeric NA    original
#>  9 am       numeric NA    original
#> 10 gear     numeric NA    original
#> 11 carb     numeric NA    original

# now add roles
rec <- 
  rec %>% 
  update_role(mpg, new_role = "outcome") %>% 
  update_role(-mpg, new_role = "predictor") 
summary(rec)
#> # A tibble: 11 x 4
#>    variable type    role      source  
#>    <chr>    <chr>   <chr>     <chr>   
#>  1 mpg      numeric outcome   original
#>  2 cyl      numeric predictor original
#>  3 disp     numeric predictor original
#>  4 hp       numeric predictor original
#>  5 drat     numeric predictor original
#>  6 wt       numeric predictor original
#>  7 qsec     numeric predictor original
#>  8 vs       numeric predictor original
#>  9 am       numeric predictor original
#> 10 gear     numeric predictor original
#> 11 carb     numeric predictor original
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot, @topepo (Max!!) Really appreciate it!